# Time consumed by sigtimedwait function in C

Tags: c, signals

The `sigtimedwait()` function can be interrupted by a signal that is defined in the set. But how can I get the time it took for the timeout to expire? Or the time consumed?

Comment: Get the current time with `gettimeofday()` before calling `sigtimedwait()`, then call `gettimeofday()` again after the signal and take the difference.

Comment: Yes, that is an option I had considered. But is time extracted from the `sigtimedwait()` function itself? Any parameter, or using any associated function..

Comment: According to the manual page, that is not possible.

Comment: In theory, you should prefer [`clock_gettime()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/clock_gettime.html) to [`gettimeofday()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/gettimeofday.html), though `gettimeofday()` is more widely available.  (Note that macOS Sierra 10.12 added support for `clock_gettime()`; older versions of Mac OS X did not support it.)